# why there is C++ program result difference between linux and windows (visual studio) platforms

Tags: linux, windows, fft, precision, trigonometry

when I did FFT computing in Both Linux and Windows platform, I found that the same programming may generate different results in these two platforms, I found that reason is that the func of sin and cos math fun generate different results for some cases, is this caused by floating point precision? since most times of computing may have the same results using linux and windows, only some value computing are different, are there any good way to solve that? Thanks a lot!

Thanks for reply and advice!

---

xre=cos(w); 
  xim=-sin(w);

---

I found that if these two expressions will influence the value, so it seems that it caused by sin and cos funcs. I have already tried to use taylor series func to represent sin and cos funcs, but the results are still different.

Comment: Depends on the compiler and its optimization/code generation flags.

Comment: Can you post an example of code that has different behavior on different platforms?

Comment: Some compilers have `long long double` types that work with 80 bits precision; others have only 64 bits. Not sure if this influences the result of trigonometric calculations though. How large are the differences?

Comment: Floating-point numerical precision is a common thing to deal with. (1) Use `almost_equal` at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon to compare the two results. (2) See Numpy’s [`isclose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) function for how they compare floats. (3) In my unit tests, if two numbers ought to be equal, I make sure that `abs(actual - expected) / abs(expected) < (1e3 * epsilon())`, for `std::numeric_limits::epsilon()`, and `1e3` because I usually can accept variability in the last 3 digits of a 16-digit number.